# Where can I find a Haynes manual/equivalent for Suzuki Alto

Tags: manual-transmission, suzuki, service

I've bought a Suzuki Alto (also known as a Maruti Alto in India) and have found it very difficult to obtain a Haynes manual for it. Does one exist in the UK, or is there an equivalent source to go to when servicing my vehicle?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there isn't a Haynes manual for the Alto.

There are a few pdf manuals online, but I'm not going to vouch for their quality when compared with Haynes, nor for their legality.

Have a look on the Suzuki forums and see what they say.

Comment: I agree with you, I couldn't find one in the UK or even the Internet.

Comment: From my experience, though, while I consider Haynes better than Chilton, both are nothing compared to factory manuals. For Mk. 3 Golf Haynes was next to useless. And factory one, from Bentley Publishing is the bomb, if expensive (it only cost me $80 (£50), so really, not that much for what you are getting).